# No Data message for report run from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report I built in BIDS that's being run from a SharePoint intranet site. In BIDS, when there is no data that meets the parameters selected by the user, it displays an error message. On the SharePoint site, however, if there is no data, it does nothing; this confuses the end-user into thinking that some parameter has been left blank or that the report is malfunctioning.

Is there a way to get the report, when run from SharePoint, to display some sort of 'No Data' message?

Comment: When you say "displays an error message", how have you implemented this, for example the Tablix level `NoRowsMessage` property?

Comment: Yes, I used the NoRowsMessage property.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this would happen, but you can use something like this as a workaround:

Consider a simple table:

[image]

The table footer row has its Row Visibility set as:

```
=IIf(CountRows() = 0, false, true)
```

This means the row will only display when there are no table rows, i.e. giving a clear indication to users as required.

Tables has rows, footer row is not shown:

[image]

Tables has no rows, footer row is shown:

[image]

The only thing I can suggest for the **NoRowsMessage** issue is creating a new, simple report containing a table with this property as a control and seeing if you get the same issue in this new report; if not, there's something going on with your existing table and I would recommend recreating the table.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this issue? Was the alternative offered any help?